# Change generic class type into subclass

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

I have this method:

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collectionView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
        if (indexPath == nil){
            NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
        } else {
            UICollectionViewCell* cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                        if ([cell isKindOfClass:[MWGradeCell class]]){
                NSLog(@"Yes");
            //here I would like to get a custom property "cell.gradeLabel.text" that is specific to MWGradeCell
            } else{
               NSLog(@"No");
            }
        }

    } else{
        NSLog(@"ended");
    }

}
```

It recognizes which UICollectionviewcell of a UICollectionview is long-pressed.
My UICollectionView is built with different types of subclassed UICollectionViewCells, each of them with different properties.

Now, I only want to get a property of a specific cell type, but in order to do that, I somehow need to change the recognized UICollectionViewCell into a MWGradeCell.

No clue how. Luckily, you people are around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but you can just cast cell like:

```
MWGradeCell* cell = (MWGradeCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

cannot remember if `(MWGradeCell *)` is really necessary

Comment: Thanks, I did that. But the app crashed on different classes. Then I tried the code above. I should have combined the two approaches. And yes, the (MWGradeCell *) IS necessary, otherwise the cellforitematindexpath won't work.